# Canceling running queries from cli

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I am looking for a way to cancel queries that are currently running from cli.

I have found these links:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/libpq-cancel.html
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/contrib-dblink-cancel-query.html

but seems that it is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the `pid` of the session running the query (the process ID of the corresponding backend process, which you can find in [`pg_stat_activity`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW), or from `ps`, `top`, etc.), you can use:

```
psql -c "SELECT pg_cancel_backend(<your_pid>)"
```

If you're trying to kill all queries meeting some criteria (e.g. those which have been running/blocking/idle for some period of time, or those running against a particular database), something like this is often useful:

```
psql -c "SELECT pg_cancel_backend(pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE <your_conditions>"
```

You can also disconnect them using `pg_terminate_backend(pid)`.

---

To cancel the most recently started query:

```
SELECT pg_cancel_backend(pid)
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE pid <> pg_backend_pid()
ORDER BY query_start DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

`pg_backend_pid()` is the connection you're using to run the command; without this filter, the "latest query" would be the one you're currently executing.

Comment: @Nick_Barnes Ok, few more questions:
1) can I get from within PostgreSQL the id of the latest query? 2) or cancel the latest query?